# cannot convert value of type [Int] to specified type 'Int'

Tags: swift

So I've been trying to make an average function using Swift. It seemed to be working, but when I try to pass an array through it, it keeps coming up with the same error.

Here's my code:

```
var prices = [6,9,4,2,10]
print("Prices: \(prices)")

func average(_ nums: Int...) -> Float{
    var sum = 0
    var numT = 0
    for num in nums{
        sum += num
        numT = nums.count
    }
    return Float(sum/numT)
}

print(average(prices))
```

And here's the error:

```
cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to specified type 'Int'
```

I'm still a beginner to Swift, so I don't really know what I'm doing. Any help please?

Comment: I put the Q/A in my vote to close. You're probably looking for [params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) but Swift doesn't have that feature.

Comment: After looking through the link, I made a different function and it seems to be working fine. I guess it's just that one function I posted. I'll just start it over. Thanks for the help!